# Using jQuery binds for "everything"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I've been falling in love with jQuery bind. The reason is that it grants me easy access to the event - and a uniform way to make functionality accessible. Here are examples:

```
$menu = $('<span id="menuid"></span>');

$menu.bind('populate', function() {
    // put stuff in the menu
}

$menu.trigger('populate');
```

Which is exactly the same as this:

```
$menu = $('<span id="menuid"></span>');

var _populateMenu = function() {
    // put stuff in the menu
}

_populateMenu();
```

But I can string all the binds together, and also - as said earlier - do the same for 'populate', 'place', 'hide', 'show' etc. I've written rather large jQuery plugins with nothing but binds - and profiled it for speed and calls. The bind method uses marginally more time and calls than the "normal" way.

An added benefit from this is that I can easily just trigger stuff from anywhere. Like 
this:

```
$("#" + menuid).trigger('placement');
```

While if I want access to the functions in the jQuery-plugin, I'd need to assign it to a variable to do so.

So - is there really anything in the way of doing it this way? Or should I keep functions as functions and only bind on actual events (like show, hide, keyup etc)? I just find this stuff extremely powerful. But I fear that it has a cost that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Being able to "trigger stuff from anywhere" is not a good thing. It's going to turn into a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Sounds like you're falling in love with OOP, and not just jquery. Is your question more semantic, or are you asking functionality limitations?

Comment: @meagar My experience is that when managed carefully it doesn't have any particularly nasty architectural problems, and in fact, by delegating some of the management to the well-tested jQuery internals, it actually *reduces* the chances for bugs.

Comment: @Mikhail I'm wondering about the functionality, really. If there are any strong limitations to doing it this way. It's very convenient. Being able to write this: `$menu.trigger('populate').trigger('position').trigger('show');` is really fun and easy. I've solved the debugging issues by having good control on my console.log messages. I'm not really having any problems with debugging, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of doing things that way is that it decouples your independent blocks of code, and makes it possible to trigger behavior without the code having to even know if such behavior is present on a particular page.

There's a cost, as you say, but depending on your application it may be worth it.  If the code needs to invoke functionality thousands and thousands of time per "keypress" event, then probably it's a bad idea.  But a dozen or two function calls vs. event triggers really isn't going to add up to much time in modern browsers.

I would also say that when the functionality in question has nothing to do with the DOM, then using the jQuery event system would be a fairly weird anti-pattern, and I'd avoid that.